# Chrome Extension notification : Different position, notification timeout and design

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am currently learning to use the Chrome Extension API's.

in my simple Chrome extension im using the notifications API

What im trying to do is something similar to :
https://www.tipranks.com/extension

my questions are :
1) How can I cause the notification to appear in a given Tab?
2) How can I change the notification timeout?(I want it to disappear only if the user clicks the 'X')
3) How can I pop another another notification in other position in my window?
4) How can I design my own GUI inside the notification?

Maybe I'm using wrong terms and someone can guide me,
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you'll need to use a content script and not the notifications API

Comment: Can you please go into details?

Comment: Close voting as too broad. @CD.. did point into the right direction - instead of using notifications, you have to write your own GUI and inject it into the page's DOM (which is all sorts of complicated fun).